# Was Bhai Mati Das sawn in half on the orders of Mughal Emperor Aurangzeb?

Tags: history

I came across this [History SE question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/24296/was-the-sikh-martyr-mati-das-sawed-in-half-on-the-orders-of-aurangzeb) that doubts the claim by Wikipedia that Sikh man [Bhai Mati Das](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhai_Mati_Das) was sawn into two on the express orders of [Aurangzeb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aurangzeb) in the 17th Century.

User Tyler Durden answered it and wrote:

> The executioners devised the most cruel ways to execute the disciples, of
>   whom Mati Das was one, in order to try to persuade Tegh Bahadur to recant.

After searching the net for a while, I found [this book](https://books.google.ch/books?id=CLCBJiEHs4cC&pg=PA216&dq=%22mati+das%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYkv-Gh4jQAhUBqI8KHT3KBUwQ6AEIPTAF#v=onepage&q=%22mati%20das%22&f=false) that agrees with that claim:

[image: Mati das sawed]

But this claim is disputed by this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guru_Tegh_Bahadur):

> No contemporary detailed accounts of the circumstances of his arrest and execution have survived either in Persian or Sikh sources. The only accounts available are those written about a 100 years later, and these accounts are conflicting.

Comment: @community I would like to know why my question doesn't show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful. If you don't say why it's bad, how would I improve it?

Comment: You say the claim is disputed by the Wikipedia page, but quote a section that doesn't dispute it?

Comment: @Oddthinking I have corrected the quotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such evidence available. The Hindu states:

> For the historians, difficulties have been created because the
>   execution of Guru Tegh Bahadur in Delhi in 1675 is not mentioned in
>   any of the contemporary Persian sources. Nor are there any Sikh contemporary accounts,

The books that mention this event are based on the testimony of some Sikhs.

> those written towards the end of the 18th century depending on ``the
>   testimony of trustworthy Sikhs''. They are, therefore, often
>   conflicting.

The earliest written account of this event was written more than 100 years after it happened.

> The earliest account of the events leading to the Guru's execution is
>   in Siyar-ul- Mutakharm by Ghulam Husain Taba- Tabai in 1780, more than
>   100 years afterwards.

[The Hindu Newspaper](http://www.thehindu.com/thehindu/2001/10/16/stories/05162524.htm)